# EXCEL - VBA recorded macro giving runtime error "1004"

Tags: vba, excel

I made a short VBA code which basically just AutoFits text/content inside cells. I recorded this macro and then remade it so that the code would run through the whole sheet:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    lastRowIndex = 2600
```

```
For rowIndex = 0 To lastRowIndex
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value <> "" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight < 10.7 Then
            If ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight > 8 Then
                ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).Select
                With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                    .WrapText = True
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = False
                End With
                Selection.Rows.AutoFit
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next rowIndex
```

End Sub

The application stops at the IF conditions. They're there because I don't want to affect all the cells, just the ones I need to modify.

When I try to run this code it gives me a this Runtime Error "1004" - Aplication-defined or Object-defined error. I have no idea why...

I tried putting Option Explicit above the code since I read somewhere it then gives you a more detailed information about the error but that doesn't seem to work either. I've never really used VBA before so I have no clue what's the reason for the error.

(Also why is  a part of the code above shifting to the left? I cant fix it)

Answer (score 0):

**CELLS()** indexing starts at 1 so:

```
For rowIndex = 1 To lastRowIndex
```

*(There may be other errors.)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code
2. Give your sub a meaningful name
3. As mentioned, loop from 1
4. Use an explicit worksheet reference (not activesheet), and hold that in a `With` statement then use the dot operator within
5. Use `vbNullString` rather than empty string literal `""` for faster comparisons
6. Combine `If` conditions into one line to reduce nesting and enhance readability
7. Use `With` statement to hold reference to current row
8. Use `Long` not `Integer` as working with rows and in future this could risk overflow with larger numbers
9. Currently `lastRowIndex` is a constant so declare as such

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FormatRows()
    Const lastRowIndex As Long = 2600
    Dim rowIndex As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rowIndex = 1 To lastRowIndex
            If Not .Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
                If .Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight > 8 And .Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight < 10.7 Then
                    With .Rows(rowIndex)
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                        .WrapText = True
                        .Orientation = 0
                        .AddIndent = False
                        .IndentLevel = 0
                        .ShrinkToFit = False
                        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                        .MergeCells = False
                        .AutoFit
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```